# How can one invoke sbt's zinc incremental compiler on Windows 7?

Tags: sbt

I've downloaded and unzipped the .tgz file and see the lib and bin directories.  I assume the binaries are linux only and I do see half a dozen or so jar files in the lib directory but don't have a clue how to fire up zinc.  Any help appreciated.  I'm a bit surprised since SBT is cross-platform!

Comment: You have downloaded what? And what do you want to do with zinc?

Answer (score 0):

You need a bash environment on windows. For me, I use git bash. Once in terminal, navigate to the bin folder of zinc and type:

```
zinc -start
```